# Writing a search result with many elements as a CSV

Tags: r, csv, row, export-to-csv

I am trying to save results of an R `search` code as a `CSV` in R, but it says:

```
"arguments imply differing number of rows"
```

The data in the 6 elements of the data frame look different from each other. I tried several solutions I found for the differing number of rows error to no avail. Can this be done, or is there at least a way I can create a list of the elements? Thanks.

Here's a look ("searchcode" is my other code I wrote, and write_csv is from the tidyverse package):

```
...
x <- searchcode(place,"search term") #this part works fine

write_csv(data.frame(x), "results.csv") #then comes the error
```

Comment: Can you share the output of running `dput(x)` in the body of your question? We have no way of knowing what structure of data you are running `data.frame()` and then `write_csv()` on, so it's going to be hard for us to diagnose the issue without more info.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO!
A clever thing to do is to alway name the packages you are using in your code. 
Where does `searchcode()` come from? Also, `write_csv()` is not base R.

Comment: We need to know what kind of output is produced by `searchcode()`. Likely, it is giving you a list with elements of different lengths. Data frames are a type of list, but with a certain restriction: All elements have to be of the same length. This makes sense: A table is rectangular, all columns must have the same lengths. Maybe you are only interested in one element of that list? Then address it specifically.